# Visual Studio 2017 cannot communicate with SQL Server 2008: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2017

After a recent upgrade to Visual Studio 2017, my C# program (Windows forms, not IIS) can no longer connect to SQL Server 2008.

Please note this should not be code related since I cannot connect not even from the Server Explorer tab in Visual Studio when I try to add a new connection (this was fine a couple of days ago). The problem is not on the SQL Server either, since I can run queries using the SQL Server Management Studio on the physical server without any problems. In fact, after further troubleshooting, other PCs in the network with the same version of VS 2017 can connect without any issues.

The problem is very specific to my development PC. The error that returns, in full, is this:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.)

Searching on the internet says it is a problem with TLS, but this was fine just two days ago. I have added this line to see if it helps, but not good (neither TLS 1.2 or SSL 3 or both):

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; //.Ssl3;
```

The project was originally compiled with .NET Framework 4.6.1, tried to change to 4.5, still nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/882979/sql-2008-on-windows-2008-r2-not-working-when-tls-1-0-and-1-1-is-disabled

Comment: Thanks, but not related, the SQL server is fine, I can do queries using the SQL server management studio on the physical server without any issues.  The problem is when connecting to the server from my development PC.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 [is dead](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/blogs/sqlreleaseservices/end-of-mainstream-support-for-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-2008-r2), you better switch to a newer version

Comment: You said that you try `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; //.Ssl3;` - you need to try `.Tls` or `.Tls11`

Comment: I guess Visual Studio just drop (or, hopefully, just disable) support for `TLS` and `TLS1.1` as they are insecure

Comment: Nothing, none of them work ... please note that I cannot connect not even from the Server Explorer tab ...

Comment: Based on my search, I also couldn't find an effective solution. But I can give you a suggestion. I recommend you use the built-in database of vs2017, you can export the database script in Sql server2008 firstly, then execute the script in the built-in database of vs2017. Finally you can access your vs built-in database.

Comment: True, that is what I am doing for some processes that I am testing, but if I cannot access the DB in the server, the real data calculated and stored by other processes is not accessible to me, rendering this method useless.